# Does Android Studio have an option to automatically scan inactive tabs for errors/warnings/lint etc?

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, ide, lint

I would like to be able to have all tabs to automatically scan lint and other warnings while they are inactive. Currently, only the active tab will load. But I prefer Android Studio to load all the tabs while I am away alt tabbed or doing other stuff while waiting for Android Studio to load. Right now I have to manually click on the tab and wait, and then click the next tab and wait. My PC is slow so it takes awhile to load each tab.

Answer (score -1):

`Analyze > Inspect Code...` will probably cover your use case. Please see https://developer.android.com/studio/write/lint#manuallyRunInspections for more details.